# What preposition should I use after " unknown"?

Tags: prepositions

You are unknown to them? Or you are unknown for them?
Any trick to find it out?

Answer (score 1):

Here 'to' mean 'by', You can use 'to'–You are unknown to them.(We use it in some passive sentence)

Comment: That seems very incomplete as it is possible to use unknown followed by other prepositions. Could you edit t give more details?

Comment: 'To' is generally used after unknown which implies 'by'